# Regex to remove namespace and convert first letter to lowercase

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use jxpath to navigate through generated java objects. I have the navigate structure in the form of an xpath

```
a:FirstElement/aa:SecondElement/aaa:ThirdElement
```

I need to get the string in the following format

```
firstElement/secondElement/thirdElement
```

How can I do this using regex in Java?

Comment: Why not simply use a String#replaceAll(regex, "") where regex = "\\w+:" ?

Comment: did you want to convert the first letter to lowercase?

Comment: it does not camelcase the element names. I was wondering if it was possible just using regex without additional code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".+?:((.+?/)|(.+?$))").matcher(s);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while(m.find()) {
        int i = sb.length();
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1));
        sb.setCharAt(i, Character.toLowerCase(sb.charAt(i)));
    }
    s = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way:

```
public static void main(String[] argv)
  {
    String str = "a:FirstElement/aa:SecondElement/aaa:ThirdElement";

    String[] splits = str.split("/?[a-z]*:");

    String finalStr = "";
    for (String s : splits)
    {
      if (!finalStr.isEmpty())
      {
        finalStr += "/";
      }
      finalStr += s;
    }

    System.out.println(finalStr);
  }
```

Comment: CThonic's regex does the same as above. But again, I need to again traverse the modified string and camel case the elements. Is there a shorter way?